# Expression of uncertainty measurement

Tags: measurements

I have a problem with the expression of a measurement result.

I have a resistance decade box used as variable resistor in order to balance a Wheatstone Bridge. Let's call this resistance decade box $R_c$.

The value of $R_c$ balancing Wheatstone bridge is $5000.0\ \Omega$ (the resolution of the decade box is $0.1\ \Omega$).

The uncertainty of resistance decade box, depending on the value of $R_c$, is in my case, $0.001\ \Omega$.

Since the uncertainty have to be expressed with only one significant digit, and since the resolution of the decade box is minor than $0.001\ \Omega$, how can I express the value of $R_c$ with its uncertainty?

Comment: I'm unclear what the notation \Ohm means, but if your uncertainty is 1/100 of the resolution, then your uncertainty is +-0.001 Ohms.  That's 1 significant digit.

Answer (score 3):

Device uncertainty is composed of two factors: calibration or offset and scale or measurement. The former is accuracy and the latter precision.

The first factor $\pm 0.1\ \Omega$ is likely the scale/measurement uncertainty. It states the degree to which you can repeatably measure a value. Alternatively, it expresses the range within which measured values will report the same value on the device. By example, for your case, input values between 99.9 to 100.1 (rounded up here, it is really 100.0$\bar{9}$) will report as 100.0.

As an aside, the term "resolution" is perhaps a misnomer. When this is the step size of the tick marks, then your scale/measurement uncertainty is half this value, or $\pm 0.05\ \Omega$. In this case, input values between 99.95 and 100.04$\bar{9}$ will report as 100.

The second factor $\pm 0.001\ \Omega$ is likely quoted as a percentage of the setting. Assume that your device has absolutely no offset errors (i.e. an input value of zero reads exactly zero). This value says that your device propagates internal errors to read any value above zero with this level of accuracy.

The final report of total uncertainty uses the rule of summation of variances. Variances are the squares of uncertainty values. So, the total is a quadrature sum of calibration and measurement:

$$ S_T^2 = \sigma^2_C + \sigma^2_M$$

The total in this case is $\sqrt{0.1^2 + 0.001^2} = 0.1$. The total is dominated by the scale / measurement uncertainty. Use $\pm 0.05$ when you mean to use the step size of the device readings for the first factor.

Comment: I took the use of "resolution" to mean that is the increments in which it could be adjusted,

Comment: I have updated my reply accordingly.